# kubernetes set env variable

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

My requirement is inside pod there is a file
location : /mnt/secrets-store/environment

In kubernetes manifest file i would like to set environment variable . Values contains above location flat file

pls share your thought how to achieve that

I have tried below option in the k8s yml file but not working

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-api
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-api 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-api
        aadpodidbinding: azure-pod-identity-binding-selector        
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sample-api
        image: sample.azurecr.io/sample:11129
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
          value: "Kubernetes"
        - name: NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME
          value: $("/usr/bin/cat" "/mnt/secrets-store/environment")
```

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible but have you looked at the possibility of creating `Secret` object and [adding environment variable referencing the secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-secret-as-container-environment-variables)?

Comment: Does Krishna Chaurasia's comment answer your question ?

Comment: Not answered my question @matt_j

Comment: for better understanding im explaining again inside following file there is some value /mnt/secrets-store/environment . That has to be exported as env variable inside the pod. Then only developer able to access those access those values from the dot net application .

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your  `/mnt/secrets-store/environment` file ?
Is this file inside the Pod or on the host machine ?
What do you mean by: `only developer able to access those access those values` ?

Comment: following file  /mnt/secrets-store/environment from keyvault secret mounted as a volume into the running pods. The challenge is when logging into the pod and cat /mnt/secrets-store/environment able to get the values . But from dot net application having  some challenges . So developers asked to me instead of flat file give environment variable inside the pod

Comment: What's exactly in this `/mnt/secrets-store/environment` file ?
Maybe a simple Bash script that will export appropriate variables is enough.

Comment: environment is mounted from azure keyvault to aks pod as a flat file . Inside that file has some value . those vaule needs to export as environment variable inside the pod.

Comment: @newbee What do you think about this method: [set your Environment Variable to Reference a Kubernetes Secret](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/configurations/set-env-var/) ?